# Output size is gradually decreased in EPS to PDF conversion

Tags: floats, pdf, eps, size

I am including .eps files in a LaTeX document into a 3x3 array, and they are converted to .pdf automatically.

```
\begin{figure}[!t] \centering
\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{f1.eps}
\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{f2.eps}
\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{f3.eps}
\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{f4.eps}
\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{f5.eps}
\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{f6.eps}
\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{f7.eps}
\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{f8.eps}
\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{f9.eps}
\caption{Something \label{fig:x}}
\end{figure}
```

All is good but somehow the document size of converted .pdf files are gradually decreased, although .eps files are all the same in size (8x8 cm). First .pdf document (f1-eps-converted-to.pdf) is 96x74 mm and last .pdf document is (f9-eps-converted-to.pdf) is 83x74 mm.

You can see the gradual change in size here:
[image]

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please provide small, compilable document with your figure, which we can test as it is. BTW, images in rows should be separated with `\hfil`, rows of images with empty row.

Comment: Welcome! Try to look at the `%%BoundingBox:` line in the `.eps` files. My guess is that they are not exactly the same...